# HTTP POST in Node.js not working

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets, express

From nodejs i am trying to post data to another URL 127.0.0.1:3002 (in file poster.js),
but when i try to access it on server at 127.0.0.1:3002 then posted data is not coming:

My  poster.js looks like this:

```
var http = require('http');

function post() {

    var options = {
        host : '127.0.0.1',
        port : 3002,
        path : '/note/',
        method : 'POST'
    };

    var req = http.request(options, function(res) {
        res.setEncoding('utf8');
        res.on('data', function(chunk) {
            console.log('BODY: ' + chunk);
        });
    });

    req.on('error', function(e) {
        console.log('problem with request: ' + e.message);
    });

    req.write("<some>xml</some>");
    req.end();
}

post();
```

and my server code in app.js is:

```
var express=require('express');
app=express();

app.post('/note',function(req,res){
    console.log(req.params);
})

app.listen(3002);
console.log('sweety dolly')
```

my server console is showing:

```
sweety dolly
[]
```

req.params is showing [] that means it received nothing while sending i am sending xml

in two different command line
i am firing two different processes like

```
 node app
```

and then in next command line

```
 node poster
```

What am i doing wrong????

Comment: Are you sure about `method : 'GET'` in a supposed POST operation? EDIT: I see you changed it, still not working?

Comment: while trying it was post only but at end i changed it to GET By mistake,any way still its not working

Comment: `ses.setEncoding('utf8');` A typo?

Comment: I'm not sure here (why I'm commenting instead of answering), but can you really just send xml like that and hope that express understands it? I would assume that you at least have to set the content-type header (`headers: { Content-Type: 'text/xml' }`, assuming that express supports that) or send the body url-encoded to receive the xml as a named string (`req.write('xml=<some>xml</some>');`, should be available in express as req.params.xml).

Comment: even when i write req.write("please send this"); its not working

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your client works, but when you `POST`, the data does not show up in `params` on the server by default (actually, params is for routing info)

Since you're posting raw data, you'll need to collect the data yourself to use it, for example by `use`ing your own simple body parser;

```js
var express=require('express');

app=express();

app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  var data = '';
  req.setEncoding('utf8');
    req.on('data', function(part) {      // while there is incoming data,
       data += part;                     // collect parts in `data` variable
    }); 

    req.on('end', function() {           // when request is done,
        req.raw_body = data;                 // save collected data in req.body
        next();
    });
});

app.post('/note',function(req,res){
    console.log(req.raw_body);               // use req.body that we set above here
})

app.listen(3002);
console.log('sweety dolly')
```

EDIT: If you want the data as a parameter, you'll need to change the client to post the data as a querystring with a name for the data;

```
var http = require('http');
var querystring = require('querystring');

function post() {

    var post_data = querystring.stringify({ xmldata: '<some>xml</some>' })

    var options = {
        host : '127.0.0.1', port : 3002, path : '/note/', method : 'POST',
        headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
          'Content-Length': post_data.length
        }
    };

    var req = http.request(options, function(res) {
        res.setEncoding('utf8');
        res.on('data', function(chunk) {
            console.log('BODY: ' + chunk);
        });
    });

    req.on('error', function(e) {
        console.log('problem with request: ' + e.message);
    });


    req.write(post_data);
    req.end();
}

post();
```

Then you can just use the standard `bodyParser` to get the data from the `param` function;

```
var express=require('express');

app=express();

app.use(express.bodyParser());

app.post('/note',function(req,res){
    console.log(req.param('xmldata'));
})

app.listen(3002);
console.log('sweety dolly')
```

Comment: Thanks for replying
 Then is there any way if i want the data in req.params.

Comment: @WebServer Added a sample of how to get it named from the `req.param` function.